# Case Statement not adding up all values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a Case Statement to multiply the cost of a product depending on position in the building. My Case statement will only add in the value from one record. My SQL skills are not great so it is probably just a simple syntax error that I can not figure out

```
SELECT ISNULL (SUM(Cost), 0),  
CASE 
 WHEN (Position = 'RC' AND Vinyl != 'N/A') THEN SUM( Cost * .40) 
 WHEN (Position = 'RC' AND Vinyl = 'N/A') THEN SUM( Cost * .75)
 WHEN (Position = 'QW' AND Vinyl != 'N/A') THEN SUM( Cost * .45)
 WHEN (Position = 'QW' AND Vinyl = 'N/A') THEN SUM( Cost * .80)
 WHEN (Position = 'PR' AND Vinyl != 'N/A') THEN SUM( Cost * .80)
   END 
 FROM InternalRemakes
WHERE RemakeDate = DATEADD(day, 0, @Date) GROUP BY Position, Vinyl 

Cost Vinyl   Position
9.43    = N/A RC
9.43 = N/A  RC
10.51   != N/A RC
23.4 != N/A     RC
57.95 != N/A    PR
```

With my query I am only getting a value of 10.51 after the CASE statement. All records in table should be able to run through the CASE statement and then add up for a total amount.

Comment: What is the output you desire? Can you provide something you expect from the statement?

Comment: What does "only add in the value from one record" mean?   I think an example would help a lot.

Comment: Your DATEADD seems redundant, as does your ISNULL

Comment: From the InternalRemakes table I want to add up all records to display a total cost per day. Depending on Position in the shop I need the Cost to be multiplied by the (.40, .75, .45, .80, .80). The Group By Position, and Vinyl might be wrong I just threw it in there because I got an error saying position and vinyl are not part of a group by clause or aggregate function. I hope this makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need the CASE statement inside SUM():

```
SELECT 
  ISNULL(SUM(Cost), 0),  
  SUM(Cost * 
    CASE 
      WHEN (Position = 'RC' AND Vinyl != 'N/A') THEN .40 
      WHEN (Position = 'RC' AND Vinyl = 'N/A') THEN .75
      WHEN (Position = 'QW' AND Vinyl != 'N/A') THEN .45
      WHEN (Position = 'QW' AND Vinyl = 'N/A') THEN .80
      WHEN (Position = 'PR' AND Vinyl != 'N/A') THEN .80
    END
  ) 
FROM InternalRemakes
WHERE RemakeDate = DATEADD(day, 0, @Date) --<-----What is this?
GROUP BY Position, Vinyl
```

Comment: I know it was the OP's code but the DATEADD function is useless. It will return the same value as @Date. :) But this is the right answer.

Comment: @SeanLange To tell the truth I did not even notice it.

Comment: @Lreyes527 are you trying to maybe want this as a date? Maybe RemakeDate is a date datatype?

Comment: The DATEADD is just inexperience with SQL. I updated my answer with records from my table and what my query results were.    @forpas your query returned the same result as mine

Comment: @Lreyes527 If this is sample data then post expected results.

Comment: @Lreyes527 If you think that with this code you can get the sum of all the rows of the table you are wrong. You do a `group by` meaning you get partial sums for each group. If you want the total sum then you have to remove `group by`

Comment: I removed the GROUP BY and it just gave me a total sum of the Cost column which is 110.72. Running all the records through the CASE statement should return a total value around 56. I apologize my inexperience made this very difficult.

Comment: I don't have your data and the sample you posted is incomplete. Post a sample including the column Vinyl so I can test.

Comment: Without the column Vinyl, see this demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dd8c7c6ebebb274d212784e96f9f6185

Comment: I added vinyl column data. I did it from my phone so it didnt align good.

Comment: See this:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=08f6b5f39af7acbf345eb8d235dedec6

Comment: Your answer was correct. I found out the problem was with my code outside of the query in my program.